# How can I change the default programs that open Outlook email attachments?

Tags: macos, applications, ms-office, defaults

On my MacOS Catalina I chose already to always open JSON files with VSCode. This works from Finder.

But from Outlook (for Mac v16.35), when I get receive an email with a JSON attachment, the file icon shows the Xcode icon and the Open context menu or the double click on the attachment open Xcode.

How can I change the default programs such that even Outlook opens it using my system default application for that file.

I tried and did not work:

- restarting Outlook after making VScode the default application for JSON files

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer when reading [this post](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-change-default-applications-mac).

Choosing **Always Open With** in the **Open With** -> **Other...** for **one file** applies this default application ONLY to this file and it is not a system wide setting. To update the system default application for all files with a certain extension do:

- open the Finder context menu item **Get Info**
- in the **Open with** section you must select the application to open this file with
- to apply this setting for all other files with the same extension, there is the **Change All...** button below the application dropdown.

The confusion might be made because in Windows in place of the **Always Open With** MacOS option, you have the **Always use this app to open .ext files** (where `ext` is the extension of the file).